# Creating A List To Contain LINQ Results?

Tags: c#, linq

How do I define resultList to allow storing database rows?

```
List<WhatType?> resultList = new List<WhatType?>();

if(someBool){
    resultList = db.table.where(a=>a.value>0).ToList();
}
else{
    resultList = db.table.where(a=>a.values<=0).ToList();
}
```

I can't seem to do the following because var needs an initial value:

```
var result;

if(someBool){
    result = db.table.where(a=>a.value>0).ToList();
}
else{
    result = db.table.where(a=>a.values<=0).ToList();
}
```

Is there a better way to solve my scope issues here?

Thanks!

Comment: Is 'table' still same for both if/else statements? There seems to be a lot of confussion in understanding what the problem is. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it to an empty list:

```
var result = new List<WhatType?>();
```

If using .NET 4.0 you could utilize the dynamic type, you would need to cast it however:

```
var result  = new List<dynamic>();
result = (List<dynamic>)db.Blogs.Where(b => b.ID == 1);
```

Comment: cannot assign <null> to implicitly-typed local variable

Comment: Right, to your second point, what type do I set the list to?  Is there a generic type that I can use?

Comment: Good catch, are your using .NET 4?

Comment: if you know the type of the list, you wouldn't use var, you would use the correct type no?

Comment: also, isn't the use of the dynamic keyword & casting a bit overkill in your example since you already know the type returned

Comment: Just responding to his comment, I agree it is overkill.

Comment: To clarify: `var` != `dynamic`; the two are TOTALLY different concepts. `var` allows type inference; the compiler MUST be able to discover the type of the variable at compile-time from the initialization expression. `dynamic` allows "duck-typing"; the compiler doesn't CARE what it is, so long as at runtime it Walk()s like a Duck and Quack()s like a duck. And I agree with other comments that it is probably overkill; the only way it wouldn't be is if your domain objects all had ID fields but there wasn't a code contract (abstract base or interface) to enforce it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what ORM technology are you using? How do you get the `db` object? What is the type of the collected element of `table`?

If you simply don't know, you can combine this particular statement into a conditional (ternary) expression:

```
var result = someBool 
    ? result = db.table.Where(a=>a.value>0).ToList() 
    : db.table.Where(a=>a.values<=0).ToList();
```

Won't work for all cases; for instance if you need to return `result` or pass it as a parameter to another method, you have to know the collected type you're expecting. But, for this small piece, you can let the compiler infer the type.

**EDIT:** I can't give you a better answer than this without more information as to what the variable `db` and its property `table` are. My first question was, what are you using to go between objects and the database? Is it Linq2SQL? Linq for Entities? NHibernate?

A Linq provider will, in all cases, give you an IQueryable reference, which is the base of the expression tree which will be evaluated and digested into the native query language (most often SQL). In 99% of cases, that IQueryable is strongly typed to the type of object being produced. If you plug the above code into your program, and mouse over the `var` keyword, you will get a tooltip balloon with the name and description of the inferred type. As I say, that will likely be `IQueryable<T>`, and there will be a footnote in that tooltip as to what T is in this case.

If the IQueryable is NOT generic, then the collected type will simply be Object. However, if that's the case, then the Where method will not compile because Object does not have a Value or Values property.

Comment: I can implement this, but it would be pretty messy.  I would like to think there's a better way?  Something along the lines of Dustin's suggestion where a simple arbitrary initial value is given to my list?

Comment: I thought of something nigh-on identical, but hesitated due to further thinking the OP may actually want to return this list as the result of a function. I know it's not stated, but just looking ahead: any thoughts other than deriving from a common type to be further examined?

Answer (score 0):

In Linq2SQL, results are most of the time IQueryable. When you hover mouse over your Where clause, IntelliSense will display its type

Comment: What does this have to do with anything?

Comment: It has to do with the fact that the type *is* known, the OP just doesn't... know it.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment - The OP wanted to know the type. This is one way to find it.

Comment: OK, based on other answers, I may be the one reading into the question incorrectly. I'm eager to find out.

Comment: Just to clarify, I assumed if the OP knows enough about _each_ type to use its properties in a `where` call then they'd sure as hell have a reference to determine the name of the type and hence the corresponding table type.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I do not like using var unless i have to. So define it as this:

```
List<table> resultList = new List<table>();

if(someBool){
    resultList = db.table.where(a=>a.value>0).ToList();
}
else{
    resultList = db.table.where(a=>a.values<=0).ToList();
}
```

The other answers miss the point as you want to know how to define the type. In simplest terms, define it to what ever your return type is. If you want a list of Integer, your type is List. The point to note about this is that you replace table with your table name, so if it was customers you would do:

```
List<customers> resultList = new List<table>();

if(someBool){
    resultList = db.customers.where(a=>a.value>0).ToList();
}
else{
    resultList = db.customers.where(a=>a.values<=0).ToList();
}
```

To extend @KeithS's answer you can now do the following:

```
List<customer> result = someBool ? result = db.customer.where(a=>a.value>0).ToList() 
: db.customer.where(a=>a.values<=0).ToList();
```

Hope it all makes sense :)

Comment: I think you miss the point: the instance of `table` accessed differs depending on `someBool`, AFAIG.

Comment: Then why does it have the same name in the example?  It is misleading if you are right about that.

Comment: it is the filter on the where clause that changes not the table itself, therefore you only have one type :/ I thought it was pretty clear imho.

Comment: As per my another of my comments here: OK, based on other answers, I may be the one reading into the question incorrectly. I'm eager to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the type of an element from `db.table`

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are using Linq2Sql.  If that is the case then you certainly know the result type of your query because you are performing the query on the same table in either case.  These aren't anonymous types being returned, your ORM has mapped each table to a corresponding class.

BTW, your example would lead one to believe that you are querying the same table in either case.  If that is not true then you should update the example to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
resultList = db.table.where(a=>a.value>0 && someBool || a.value<=0 && !someBool).ToList();
```